# Passing Data from Swift to PHP for JSON using file_get_contents?

Tags: php, json, swift, file-get-contents

I am new to Swift 3 and I am trying to pass some data to server using PHP. I am a beginner in both languages to be sure.

I am trying to receive a data from SWIFT to PHP.

However, I realized that with $_POST or $_REQUEST in PHP would not work for JSON. Instead, I heard that it is necessary to use 'file_get_contents' or 'PHP://input'.

So I seriously spent a lot of hours on figuring out how to make it work.

The following is the code from the PHP side. However, it seems to be working only with the Raw Data, not with JSON encode.

Does anyone think the code below is incorrect to receive the data from SWIFT?

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","123","123!!","123");

$menu_main_item_store_id = file_get_contents('php://input');
$menu_main_item_store_id_received = $menu_main_item_store_id;

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu_main_items WHERE menu_main_item_store_id=$menu_main_item_store_id_received AND menu_main_item_in_use_check = 'yes'"; 
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }
echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code within your answer formatted as code instead of a screen shot of your code.

Comment: Thank you. I put the code in. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

// You Can try this code

```
 <?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','DatabaseUserName');
define('PASS','Password');
define('DB','DataBaseName');
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
$sql = "select * from DATABAS_TABLE_NAME";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('Username'=>$row[0],
'Cell'=>$row[1],
));
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of what you've done differently compared to the question, and how to apply the same approach in other examples?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. your explanation has given me a step up. However, the problem I found was that whatever the PHP received, it posts to the array that is being sent, I think.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents('php://input')` will give you a string containing whatever data was posted to PHP. It will not automatically work out what format that data is in, so you'll need to parse the data somehow, e.g. with `json_decode()`.

Remember to check for errors in the JSON formatting, and that all input is untrusted - you don't know for sure that it's your app sending the data, somebody could figure out the URL and send something weird to break your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Swift seems to be sending correct data using POST.

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
let session = URLSession.shared
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

let paramString = "table_id='1'"
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

However, when the PHP receives it,
it returns nothing.

```
$contents = $_REQUEST['table_id']; 
$abc = $contents;


if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu_main_items WHERE table_id='".$abc."'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }
    echo json_encode($resultArray);

}
```

If I manually type $content="1"; then the data is retrieved.

What do you think the problem seems to be?